# Why isn't the Ruby 1.9 lambda call possible without the dot in front of the parentheses ?

Tags: ruby, lambda, ruby-1.9, first-class-functions

I checked out the latest Ruby version, to play a bit with the latest changes. The first thing I tried to do was call a Ruby lambda/block/proc just like you'd do with a Python callable.

```
a = lambda {|x| puts x}
a.call(4) # works, and prints 4
a[4] # works and prints 4
a.(4) # same
a(4) # undefined method 'a' for main:Object
```

Why isn't the last call possible? Will it ever be?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

AFAIK it's because ruby doesn't let you define the `()` method for an object. The reason it doesn't let you define the `()` method is probably due to the fact that parentheses are optional in method calls.

And for what it's worth, here's a hack to let you invoke lambdas using `()` http://github.com/coderrr/parenthesis_hacks/blob/master/lib/lambda.rb

Comment: can you please explain the lambda script a bit?

Comment: ok, when you try to invoke a method named `blah()` and `method_missing` is triggered it checks to see whether a lambda called `blah` is defined in the appropriate context. If such a lambda is defined then it just invokes the lambda using the usual `blah.call` syntax, it also passes along any parameters that were given

Comment: I think this is an awesome hack. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Ruby is basically 100% object-oriented, but sometimes it tries to hide this fact for... convenience? Familiarity?

Basically functions defined "at the top level" are really defined as methods on a global object. To make that work, a call without a specifier is really converted to calling a method with that name on said global object. This style makes things look more script-y. Ruby is trying to do that with your last example.

The first two examples parse fine because Ruby knows you are trying to access the methods of the proc object--remember even `[]` is just a method you can define. The one with the explicit dot also works because the dot means "send this message to this object" (in this case, `a`).

I know that doesn't "solve" anything, but I hope it helps a bit.

Comment: The fact that ruby is OOP doesn't explain why you cannot use `()` to invoke a lambda. Many languages let you define a `()` method for your objects. The question really is why doesn't ruby let you define a `()` operator?

Comment: (Just now saw this comment...) Good question. Maybe it has something to do with how you can omit parentheses in certain situations; would be weird to have an implicit overloaded operator call.