# Why no `()` operator for objects?

Tags: ruby, lambda, functional-programming

Lambdas (and procs) in Ruby are just objects with a `call` method, as in any OO language with functional programming glued on as an afterthought. There are also:

- `lambda.(<args>)`
- `lambda[<args>]`

as syntactic sugar for `lambda.call()`.

Lua allows for a `__call` meta method, that lets me call an object, and in the background, the arguments (and the table) are handed to a real function that does the actual magic.

Lambdas don't feel like dealing with real functions since they are called with `[]` or `.()` instead of `()`. Why not add a `()` operator that can be overloaded? Then `object()` would be translated to mean `object.()`, same as with `+`, `||` or any other operator.

Wouldn't it make sense to have syntactic sugar that allows calling the lambda directly? Is this more a matter of design philosophy than technical limitations?

#### Addressing some "problems" (that aren't really problems) that people have brought up:

*If a method returns a lambda, what does that method followed by () mean? does it call only the method, or also the returned lambda?*

`method()` means call `method`. If that expression returns a lambda, `method()()` would then call said lambda. The opposite would make no sense at all.

*If there is a method called foo, and a callable object called foo, what does foo() mean?*

Answer: *if foo is a method and a variable, what do you expect `foo` to evaluate to?* The variable. Ruby already does deal with this kind of ambiguity by simply choosing the more intuitive of two options. Thus, if there is a method `foo`, `foo()` should call that method. If there's a callable method `foo` in the same scope, that'd be shadowed by the real function.

Comment: I'd also be interested to know if there's any objective reason to prevent this syntax. Here's a related question (duplicate?) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343812/calling-applying-lambda-vs-function-call-the-syntax-in-ruby-is-different-why The answer isn't very satisfying though IMHO.

Comment: Here's [another explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686844/why-isnt-the-ruby-1-9-lambda-call-possible-without-the-dot-in-front-of-the-pare). Supposedly Ruby doesn't permit () to be defined on an object because the parentheses are optional in a method call. I agree though, the .() syntax drives me nuts.

Comment: Why fuss over just a single period?

Comment: @sawa: Because Ruby is all about syntactic sugar?

Comment: @chickenburgers: This makes the most sense to me.

Comment: @chickenburgers: it isn't really about "permitting it". It is simply impossible. If you were to allow it, then it would no longer be possible to know what `foo()` means.

Answer (score 5):

> Why not add a () operator that can be overloaded?

It would be ambiguous. If `object` is both, a method and a local variable, then `object` refers to the local variable, whereas `object()` invokes the method:

```
def object
  123
end
object = :abc

object   #=> :abc
object() #=> 123
```

Changing this convention would likely break existing code.

That's (presumably) why Ruby has `object.()` – it is syntactic sugar for `object.call`:

```
class MyClass
  def call
    123
  end
end

object = MyClass.new
object.call #=> 123
object.()   #=> 123
```

Having a separate syntax to call lambdas allows to distinguish between a method call and calling a lambda which is returned by that method: (thanks Amadan for pointing that out)

```
def object
  -> { 123 }
end

object    #=> #<Proc:0x007fe494110a78@(irb):2 (lambda)>
object()  #=> #<Proc:0x007fe494110a78@(irb):2 (lambda)>

object.()   #=> 123
object().() #=> 123
```

Comment: Even more so - consider `def make_yo_printer; lambda { puts "yo" }; end`. OP, under your proposal, what do you expect `make_yo_printer()` to do? Under current Ruby syntax, it is clear: `make_yo_printer` returns a lambda, `make_yo_printer()` as well, while `make_yo_printer.()` and `make_yo_printer().()` both execute it. But if `()` executes lambdas, it is not clear what do parentheses belong to in `make_yo_printer()`: to the `make_yo_printer` call, or to the returned lambda. This dilemma does not exist in Python, since `()` is always needed to execute a call.

Comment: Code having the same name for local variables and methods probably deserves to break.

Comment: @Amadan: That's the reason indeed. Methods can be called without parens.

Comment: It seems pretty obvious to me that `object()` should return a lambda; ommitting () is just syntactic sugar, after all. To call the lambda it would be `object()()`. As for the ambiguity of an object and a method sharing a name, first of all I think that's a terrible style choice, secondly in that case `object` should be the object while `object()` should be the method. Simple, isn't it? and you could still access `object.()` like with other overloaded operators (`object.+(other_object)`).

Comment: @Amadan same could be said about `method { ... }` though. Is `{ ... }` a block? is it a hash? The answer is simple, it's a block. Why? Because at some point somebody just defined it to be that way. Same goes for your example. Just make clear that `whatever()` calls `whatever` if it's a method, or tries the `()` operator if it isn't. That makes sense, is intuitive and wouldn't break any code. `make_yo_printer()` would then unambiguously call `make_yo_printer` and return a lambda, as any sane programmer would expect.

Comment: @DarkWiiPlayer: Is it really that intuitive, and something any sane programmer would expect? It is key to the design of Ruby that there is no distinction between methods and properties. `arr.size` is a method; `arr.size()` is perfectly legal but weird. Now imagine if my method wasn't called `make_yo_printer` but `yo_printer`, and normal access being `yo_printer.call`? Now would you expect it to be equivalent to `yo_printer()` or `yo_printer()()`?

Comment: If `yo_printer` returns a lambda, I'd expect both `yo_printer` and `yo_printer()` to return a lambda. Again, because `yo_printer` and `yo_printer()` should be the same according to how ruby is supposed to work. There's no ambiguity or uncertainty either; unlike in other languages, in ruby `object.attribute` is ALWAYS a method, even if its syntax makes it look like a real attribute. Also, if `yo_printer` was meant to be used like that, it'd be `print_yo`; if it returns a lambda, it's probably not meant to be called directly except in a few special cases.